# How many copies of $C_4$ are there in $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics

How many copies of $C_4$ are there in $K_n$?

I said that any 4 distinct vertices is one copy of $C_4$ in $K_n$ so there must be $n$ choose $4$ total copies of $C_4$ are there in $K_n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: When you have chosen four vertices of $K_n$ there are still three different ways to connect them to a $C_4$.

Comment: How many copies of $C_4$ are there in $K_4$?

Comment: @bof: *thunk!* (That’s the sound of head nodding all the way down to the desktop.)

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{n}{4}$ ways to chose the four vertices in the cycle. There are then $4!$ ways to write the in order. But these $4!$ ways can be separated into groups of $8$ that give the same cycles (there are $4$ rotations of the same cycle in each of the two directions).

The answer is hence $3\binom{n}{4}$